# How to patch an entire collection to a Db

Tags: powerapps

I'm struggling to update a db from a powerapp collection, the Db is structured int this way:
[image]

And my collection is structured in this way:

[image]

So far I'm able to create the collection in this way:

```
ClearCollect(ThisBudget;ForAll(BrowseGallery1.AllItems;{item:Heading1.Text;newValue:TextInput1.Text}))
```

but I'm totally unable to find the right way to patch this collection to the db, basically i need to patch the newValue field of the reletives items, what's the correct way?

I tried many things like this:

```
ForAll(ThisBudget;Patch('[dbo].[Budget]';
First(Filter('[dbo].[Budget]';Item=item));{newValue:ThisBudget.newValue}))
```

but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working with a subset of the data for each row instead of an entire entry. It also looks like you're not working with the primary key for each entry. Either one of those things can cause issues when trying to update the data source.

I have two recommendations:

- First, try to add the entry `Id`, to the table you're working with locally. Then, instead of matching on `Item` try matching on `Id`.
- Second, if the first solution didn't work, try creating a patch that contains an entire row's data instead of just some of its columns. The data source may want to work with complete entries.